# Questions about transformation, normalization and ppm files in fractals

Tags: c, normalization, transformation, fractals, ppm

I've 3 questions about a program I'm working on. The first is my transformation method correct? While at large scale it seems fine, at smaller ranges it appears to drift—suggesting an error of some sort. The second problem is about my probably pathetic attempt at normalization. I understand the concept, just not the details. How do you move from normalization polynomial to RGB is the obvious question? And lastly, you will notice in my code that I have a test when writing the ppm header. The first method which seems to follow the standard creates files with inclusions, typically red dots at the edges or in some cases what seems to be shifting of some sort?

```
/**  mandel2.c
 **
 **  to compile:  gcc -std=c11 -o mand2 mandel2.c
 **
 **/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

char *Version = "0.008";
/*

Tour of "Seahorse Valley"

-0.75 0.08 0.16 10000
-0.74548 0.11669 0.01276 15000
-0.745067 0.118346 0.0007
-0.744567 0.121201 0.002 1000
-0.7445366 0.1217208 5e-4 1500
-0.74453892 0.12172418 1e-4 2500
-0.744539761 0.121724001 6.25e-6 10000
-0.7445398671 0.1217237421 3.906e-7 25000
-0.74453985651 0.12172377365 3.072e-8
-0.7445398603558 0.1217237736544 9.6e-10
-0.74453986035590 0.12172377389443 6.0e-11
-0.744539860355905 0.121723773894425 7.5e-12
-0.74453986035590837 0.12172377389442482 8e-14
-0.744539860355908380 0.121723773894424824 6.0e-15
-0.7445398603559083806 0.1217237738944248242 7.5e-16
-0.74453986035590838081 0.12172377389442482421 9.375e-17
-0.74453986035590838012 0.12172377389442482241 1.172e-17

*/

typedef struct  {
    double centerX;
    double centerY;
    double magnify;
    int    maxiter;
    int    cv;
} Parameters;

Parameters parse_command_line ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    Parameters p;

    if (argc > 5) {
        p.cv = atoi( argv[5] );
    }
    else {
        p.cv = 64;
    }
    if( argc > 4 ) {
        p.centerX   = atof( argv[1] );
        p.centerY   = atof( argv[2] );
        p.magnify   = ( 1 / atof( argv[3] ) );
        p.maxiter   = atoi( argv[4] );
    } else {
        if( argc > 3 ) {
            p.centerX   = atof( argv[1] );
            p.centerY   = atof( argv[2] );
            p.magnify   = ( 1 / atof( argv[3] ) );
            p.maxiter   = 500;
        } else {
            if( argc > 2 ) {
                p.centerX   = atof( argv[1] );
                p.centerY   = atof( argv[2] );
                p.magnify   = 1.0;
                p.maxiter   = 500;
            } else {
                if( argc > 1 ) {
                    p.centerX   = atof( argv[1] );
                    p.centerY   = 5.0;
                    p.magnify   = 5.0;
                    p.maxiter   = 500;
                } else {
                    p.centerX   = 0.0;
                    p.centerY   = 0.0;
                    p.magnify   = 1.0;
                    p.maxiter   = 500;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    Parameters P     = parse_command_line( argc, argv );
    int width        = 500;
    int height       = 500;
    double MinRe     = ( -2.0 / P.magnify ) + P.centerX;
    double MaxRe     = ( 1.0 / P.magnify ) + P.centerX;
    double MinIm     = ( -1.2 / P.magnify ) + P.centerY;
    double MaxIm     = ( MinIm + ( MaxRe - MinRe ) * height / width );
    double Re_factor = ( MaxRe - MinRe ) / ( width - 1 );
    double Im_factor = ( MaxIm - MinIm ) / ( height - 1 );
    int test         = 0;

if (test == 1) {
    printf( "P6\n" );
    printf( "%d %d 255\n", width, height );
    printf( "# mand2.exe vr%s %0f %0f %0f %d\n", Version, P.centerX, P.centerY, P.magnify, P.maxiter );
}
else {
    printf( "P6\n# mand2.exe vr%s %0f %0f %0f %d\n", Version, P.centerX, P.centerY, P.magnify, P.maxiter );
    printf( "%d %d 255\n", width, height );
}

    for( unsigned y = 0; y < height; ++y ) {
        double c_im = MaxIm - y * Im_factor;
        for( unsigned x = 0; x < width; ++x ) {
            double c_re = MinRe + x * Re_factor;
            double complex C = c_re + c_im * I;
            double complex Z = 0;
            unsigned n = 0;
            for( ; n < P.maxiter; ++n ) {
                Z = Z * Z + C;
                if( creal( Z ) + cimag( Z ) > 4 )
                    break;
            }
            if( n < P.maxiter ) {
                int brightness = 256.0 * log( 1.75 + n - log(
                    log( cabs( Z ) ) ) ) / log( ( double ) P.maxiter );
                fputc( ( unsigned char ) brightness, stdout );
                fputc( ( unsigned char ) brightness, stdout );
                fputc( ( unsigned char ) P.cv, stdout );
            } else {
                fputc( 0, stdout );
                fputc( 0, stdout );
                fputc( 0, stdout );
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've included an image as proof of presumed idiocy…
[image: image from Seahorse Valley -0.75 0.08 0.16 10000]

Comment: I can't say much but an aside: in the check of program arguments `if( argc > 1 )` you set the default values to `sp.centerY = 5.0; p.magnify = 5.0;`. Whereas the other defaults suggest they should be `sp.centerY = 0.0; p.magnify = 1.0;`

Comment: Thanks for catching that @WeatherVane! Luck I never run with less than 4 arguments!!